# Does the Axiom of Regularity imply that all non-empty sets must have an element which is a set?

Tags: set-theory

I was reading about the Axiom of Regularity and the way I found it defined was $$\forall A(\ \exists x (x \in A) \implies \exists y \in A (\ \neg \exists z \in y (z \in A)\ ) \ )$$
And so I started thinking. Take the set $C = \{ \text{red}, \text{green}, \text{blue} \}$, or maybe the set $\mathbb{N}$. They are both non-empty, so by implication, we have that $\exists n \in \mathbb{N} (\neg \exists n' \in n (n' \in \mathbb{N}))$ and $\exists c \in C (\neg \exists c' \in c (c' \in C))$. To me, the only way I can intuitively understand statements such as $c' \in c$ is to assume that $c$ is a set initially. And since there has to be at least one such $c$, does that mean that one of the elements of $C$ or $\mathbb{N}$ are in fact, sets? Is one of the numbers secretly a set? Is one of the colour literals, as set?

Or did I go off somewhere?

Comment: In ZFC-style set theory, **everything** is a set. The whole mathematical universe is built out of the emptyset.

Comment: woah. thats wild.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZFC is usually formalized in first-order logic, which is "one sorted"; everything in the universe of discourse is of the same "type", and is a valid argument for every operation or predicate in the language.  So a formula like $x \in y$ is meaningful no matter what $x$ and $y$ are, and has to be either true or false for any given choice of $x,y$.

So if you are considering "red" to be an object in your universe of discourse, then I ask you: for which objects $x$ is it true that $x \in \text{red}$?  If there are any such $x$, then "red" is something we would think of as a set, since it has one or more elements.  What if it does not have any elements, i.e. there does not exist any $x$ such that $x \in \text{red}$?  Well, then we have $\forall x : x \in \text{red} \leftrightarrow x \in \emptyset$ (since both sides are false for every $x$), and so by the axiom of extensionality, $\text{red} = \emptyset$.  So in this case your object "red" is just another name for the empty set, and again we would think of it as a set.

This means, in effect, that in ZFC, *every* object is a set.

In the case of $\mathbb{N}$ (also called $\omega$ in set theory), its elements (the natural numbers) are indeed sets, of a very particular and important kind.  They are the finite [von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals).  So the natural number 0 is just a name for the empty set, 1 is a name for $\{ \emptyset\}$, 2 is a name for $\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}\}$ and so on.

If you drop the axiom of extensionality, it is possible to have objects that have no elements yet are not the empty set.  These are called "atoms" and the resulting axiomatic system is sometimes called "ZFC with atoms".  It is kind of interesting to think about, but doesn't really have any major advantages over ZFC as a foundation for the rest of mathematics.

Comment: wow, thats very interesting. this sent me down a side tangent of researching [many-sorted logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-sorted_logic). Fascinating stuff.